# How to push element to array in array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

Let's say I would like to create a new array of arrays

```
arr = Array.new(5,[])
=> [[], [], [], [], []]
```

How can I specifically push an element to one of those arrays?

When I try to push to only one of the arrays, the value is always added to all of them:

```
arr[3].push("foo")
=> ["foo"]

arr
=> [["foo"], ["foo"], ["foo"], ["foo"], ["foo"]]
```

Comment: See the [Common gotchas](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas) section in the docs for `Array.new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the way you're pushing, it's the way you're creating the array.

The array is initialised with 5 *references to the same array*, so when you modify one of them, all of the other copies change too.

You need to create the array using a different method, so that you create five *different arrays* rather than five *copies of the same array*. This can be done like so:

```
arr = Array.new(5) { [] }
```

The block (the bit between `{}`) is executed to create all 5 array items, so you end up with 5 different arrays.

Your code then works as expected:

```
arr = Array.new(5) { [] }
=> [[], [], [], [], []]

arr[3].push("foo")
=> ["foo"]

arr
=> [[], [], [], ["foo"], []]
```